# Win10 Electron Error: Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is

Tags: npm, electron, command-prompt, chromium, nvidia

I have an electron repo (https://github.com/MartinBarker/RenderTune) which used to work on windows 10 fine when ran with command prompt. After a couple months I come back on a new fresh windows 10 machine with an Nvidia GPU, and the electron app prints an error in the window when starting up:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getCurrentWindow')
```

Running ffmpeg shell commands results in an error as well, and in the command prompt terminal this message is outputted:

```
[14880:1207/145651.085:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(457)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
```

I checked on my other Windows laptop machines running the same exact code from the master branch of my repo, and it works perfectly fine when running locally.

It seems like this might be a recent issue? I have found it discussed in various forums:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1944468

https://www.reddit.com/r/electronjs/comments/qdauhu/passthrough_is_not_supported_gl_is_disabled_angle/

I tried upgrading my global electron npm package to a more recent version: electron@16.0.4 , but the errors still appear.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try disabling hardware acceleration using `app.disableHardwareAcceleration()` ([See the docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/v14-x-y/api/app#appdisablehardwareacceleration)). I don't think this is a fix though, it just makes the message go away for me.

---

### Example Usage

main.js

```js
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'
import isDev from 'electron-is-dev'

app.disableHardwareAcceleration()

let win = null

async function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    title: 'My Window'
  })

  const winURL = isDev
    ? 'http://localhost:9080'
    : `file://${__dirname}/index.html`
  win.loadURL(url)

  win.on('ready-to-show', async () => {
    win.show()
    win.maximize()
  })
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  win = null
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})
```

Comment: how can i enforce acceleration? to render smoothly?

Comment: @Dee I think this can be done by setting the corresponding command line switch for Chromium with `app.commandLine.appendSwitch('force_high_performance_gpu')` as described [here](https://www.electronjs.org/de/docs/latest/api/command-line-switches#--force_high_performance_gpu).

Comment: Our app, containing a 3D rendered scene, needs HW acceleration which comes enabled by default in Electron so this isn't an option for us. While I would love not to see this error, I can't seem to find any effect on the app itself so our decision is to ignore it for now.

Comment: adding app.disableHardwareAcceleration()
in index.js solved this problem for me also on electron@20.0.0 on windows 7 32bit